# localStorageService will not updated (after reload the current value is not there)

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I'm trying to update the value of a cartItem in localstorage , using localStorageService.set service.

in browser single tab it's work fine but when we copy the URL and open in other tab localStorageService.set not update the cartItem in localstorage but in console it's showing updated. after page reload it display old value instead of updated value.

Controller Code :

```
localStorageService.set('cartItem',cartItemsArray);
```

Comment: Show display code of cartItem

Comment: Get the data by $scope.cartItemsArray =  localStorageService.get('cartItem'); and display at front end

Comment: And how are you displaying it in HTML view ? One way databinding ?

Comment: by ng-repeat two way binding

Comment: Hmmm I think you should provide more code for solving this one. You are using **grevory** ng service ?

Comment: Yes, but same code working fine if i'm working on single tab

Comment: Please see this post https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/25/angularjs-real-time-model-persistence-using-local-storage/
It seems that view can't be refresh automatically even with 2way databinding